# Hide submenu if it has not children

Tags: jsf, primefaces

If I have a panelMenu component and some of its submenu components doesn't show children due to all its children have the rendered attribute set to false. What can I do to hide the submenu option?

**For example SubMenu_1_2 and SubMenu_1_3 should be hidden:**

```
<p:panelMenu>
    <p:submenu label="SubMenu_1_1">
        <p:menuitem action="#{backingBean.view_1_1_1}" value="View_1_1_1" rendered="true" />
        <p:menuitem action="#{backingBean.view_1_1_1}" value="View_1_1_2" rendered="true" />
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="SubMenu_1_2">
        <p:menuitem action="#{backingBean.view_1_2_1}" value="View_1_2_1" rendered="false" />
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="SubMenu_1_3">
        <p:menuitem action="#{backingBean.view_1_3_1}" value="View_1_3_1" rendered="false" />
        <p:menuitem action="#{backingBean.view_1_3_2}" value="View_1_3_2" rendered="false" />
        <p:menuitem action="#{backingBean.view_1_3_3}" value="View_1_3_3" rendered="false" />
    </p:submenu>
</p:panelMenu>
```

**It doesn't matter if I need to use jQuery**

Comment: Use the same mechanism as for menu item - `rendered` attribute for `p:submenu` (only condition will be more complicated: option1 or option2 ...).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Give id attribute to your panelMenu.

Step 2 Now find the component from the tree and set the rendered attribute false if children is present.

```
<p:panelMenu id="panelMenu">


for(UIComponent component: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getChildren()) {
        if(component.getId().contains("panelMenu")){
            for(UIComponent panelMenuChild:component.getChildren()){//this is the child of panelMenu ie Submenu
                if(panelMenuChild.getChildren().size()>0){
                    ((SubMenu)panelMenuChild).setRendered(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("panelMenu");
```

Step 3. then update the panelMenu;

Comment: When I need to call the method?